# Long association and decency "prevents" or "prevent" me?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement

Which is the correct usage:  'long association and decency prevents me' or is it 'long association and decency prevent me'?

Answer (score 1):

*long association and decency prevent me*
seems right as the nouns association and decency are not the same.

Comment: This is the right answer -- when there is a plural noun (such as 'conditions' / 'conventions') or 2 or more different singular nouns (long 'association' and 'decency') we should use the plural form of the verb as in 'prevent.'  However, senior members would advise you that your answer should be more detailed & contain appropriate examples, citations and link to references. You can see how by looking at the way the answers to other questions at this website have been constructed. Note: A very short answer like yours can be posted as a comment in the comments section under the original question!

Comment: @EnglishStudent  sure will do so next time onwards